Jack2 Period (-n) parameter behavior for Round-Trip Latency calculation
I am working on a c++ real-time audio app using a Jack2 client implementation for capture and playback.
On the jackd cli I can specify the buffer size (-p) as well as the number of periods (-n) with the latter having a default / min value of 2.
I have always been confused by this default value, because I assumed that the minimum number of periods would be 3: 1 period for capture, one period for processing and one period playback.
To get my thoughs in order I've tried to sketch out what I assume is happening (see image) and would like to confirm whether this is correct.
For illustrative purpose the buffer size is only 4 samples.
Variables:

tGD: ADC / DAC Group Delay or transfer delay between audio interface and in-process memory
tB: duration of a period (determined by buffer size)
n: number of periods

Process (see image)

The hardware starts capturing samples at the start of period time frame and transmits them to in-process memory
A complete buffer is ready for processing and jack calls the process callback
The audio data has been processed and written back to the output buffer. The process callback returns at this point
The output has been transferred back to the interface and each sample is played back 2tB + 2tGD after it has been captured

Questions:

Is it correct, that my round-trip latency is calculated by ntB+2tGD?
Does the period parameter have any other significance than specifying the number buffers used to transfer between interface and process memory?
Why would I ever want to use more than 2 periods, when jack reports an underrun if I don't return the callback within 1 period?

Simplyfied illustration of 2 period 4 sample buffer real-time audio processing
